# How do i create a page with forms without using models in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to create a page/view with a form containing few fields in django admin without using models. This form when submitted will make an api call to another project made in django with django rest framework that will be running parallely. How do I go about this?

Comment: You can add your own views to the Django admin (and therefore use your own forms) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites

Comment: Hey, this helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to create a custom page with a form in django admin without using models with [Timmy O'Mahony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396300/timmy-omahony)'s suggestion in the comments. The link that he suggested was "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FormView, see Django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview

In forms.py define your form and then use form in your views.py and template.html.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do a normal HTML form and would use a lightweight Javascript Framework like [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) to bind the form fields and fire away the POST RestAPI.